# What is the phpQuery equivalent of the JQuery unwrap?

Tags: php, jquery, html, phpquery

I have HTML with nested <div> tags. I have tried

```
$doc->find('div div')->unwrap();
```

and

```
foreach($doc['div div'] as $div_div)
 {
  pq($div_div)->unwrap();
 }
```

But this returned the following error:

### Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Method 'unwrap' doesnt exist'

I need to figure out how to remove the outer-most DIV tag and retain everything inside.

Here is the HTML

```
<div style="text-align: justify;">
    <div style="font-family: Times'; font-size: 13pt; text-align: center;">
          ARTICLE 1 - FAMILY, BENEFICIARIES, AND TRUST PURPOSE
    </div>
    <div style="text-align: justify;">1.1<span class="Apple-tab-span">  </span<b>Family</b>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using [contentsUnwrap()](https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/wiki/jQueryPortingState),

```
$doc->find('div div')->contentsUnwrap();
```

Comment: Awesome. It worked perfectly. What is the deal with phpQuery's lack of documentation? Is it a dead project? Should I use something else? It appears to be powerful, but figuring out how to use it is not easy.

Comment: @j_allen_morris i dont think its dead yet, only that it lacks proper documentation.. you can use it, but yes finding the usage is difficult

Comment: If I didn't have so many other projects going on, I'd like to be a part of documenting its uses. I like it. It's gotten me away from regex parsing of HTML. lol